# Why does my spa pump hum but not rotate?

Tags: hot-tub

I have a Jacuzzi spa pump model s55cxnfe-7055. When the pump turns on it hums for a few seconds then turns off.  I turned the shaft using a flat head screw driver to spin the shaft right and left with no resistance.  When I turned the breaker on, the motor hums but this time I tried to spin the shaft right when it turned on to help it self start. however when I did this I noticed the shaft would not spin at all. It was locked up.  Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like the motor is broken. it might be able to be repaired. it could be a bad sensor or a bad coil.

Comment: If the motor has a start capacitor it may have gone bad.

Comment: It may need primed. On most pumps there is a cap you can remove without tools and pour water in.

Answer (score 1):

Frozen motor could be seized bearings, jammed pump impeller or even burned/shorted motor windings.

Any of those probably mean motor and / or pump replacement.

Comment: If it is a jammed pump impeller the cause is probably hair, so it may be possible to clean.

Comment: Gents - he said he is able to turn it with his hand when not powered on. So its not a physical blockage. Possibly a bearing issue but more likely one coil energized and another not, most likely still needs a new motor

Comment: I've had impellers get jammed with things that got through a broken skimmer basket like twigs and pieces of bark.

Comment: He says at the end that it locked up.